# In Ruby, how do I calculate how close an element is to its neighbor?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of strings, which are in fact numbers ...

```
["1", "2", "3", "7", "8", "9"]
```

How do I write an expression that will tell me the percentage of elements in the array (neglecting the last one) that have an absolute value difference of 1 with the element that follows it?  So in the above, this is true for four out of the five elements, (since "7" has a difference of four following the "3" element), so I would expect the expression to return .8.

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your code and we'll help to make it work.

Comment: Just out of interest, where are you getting these challenges from? Or are creating them yourself?

Comment: A percentage would be 80% not counting the ultimate element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = ["1", "2", "3", "7", "8", "9"].map(&:to_i)
result  = arr.each_cons(2).count { |a, b| (a - b).abs == 1 }
percentage = result / (arr.count - 1).to_f
 #=> 0.8
```

Comment: `select(&block).count` is just `count(&block)`

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of ways to do that.

```
arr = ["1", "2", "3", "7", "6", "8", "7"]
```

**Step through the array and count the number of matches.**

```
100 * arr[0..-2].each_index.count do |i|
  ai, aip1 = arr[i], arr[i+1] 
  aip1 == ai.next || ai == aip1.next
end/(arr.size-1).to_f
  #=> 66.66666666666667
```

**Step with an enumerator**

```
n = 0
enum = arr.to_enum
loop do
  nxt, pk = enum.next, enum.peek
  n += 1 if nxt.next == pk || pk.next == nxt
end
(100*n)/(arr.size-1).to_f
  #=> 66.66666666666667
```

When all elements have been generated by the enumerator `enum` (which can also be defined `arr.each`) `enum.peek` raises a `StopIteration` exception (unless the array is empty, in which case `enum.next` raises the same exception). [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles that exception by breaking out of the loop.

Notice that there is no need to convert the strings to integers.